# What is the time I takes for a car to reach the end of an elastic road?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a road which has a 1 mile long section that is elastic. A car is driving 50 miles per hour. The instant it drives on to the elastic section of road the other end of it starts to move also at 50 miles per hour with the stretch distributed evenly along it's length. How long will it take the car to reach the end of the elastic section of road?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Please include your attempt to let the community know where exactly you are stuck, also question lacks clarity about the terms related to "elasticity", "moving ends" etc.